# How do i call a function of an object as if it was the property of another object?

Tags: javascript

Now this may be an odd question, but consider the following:

```
var A = {
  name: "A",
  showName: function(){console.log(this.name)}
}

var B = {
  name: "B"
}
```

I now want to call the "showName" function of A as if it was a property of B, meaning it should log "B" to the console. Is there any reasonable way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) :

```
A.showName.call(B);
```

Comment: Or of course, `apply`. Or assign it to a property on `B` and call it directly via that property...

Comment: Yes. Or `B.showName = A.showName;B.showName();`. EDIT : damn... I hadn't seen your edit...

Comment: Thanks! The .call() and .apply() was exactly what i was looking for.